# jquery - inserting a header section on an existing webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to inject a banner div

```
<div id='banner'></div>
```

on top of an existing webpage in such a manner so that when a person scrolls the webpage the banner remains on top. Also the webpage should be pushed down by the banner so that every part of the page remains accessible.

Here is my CSS:

```
#banner {
position:fixed; 
display:block; 
top:0px; 
background-color:#FFFFFF; 
width:100%; height:250px; 
border:2px solid; 
}
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$("body").prepend("<div id='banner'></div>");
```

I tried using jquery to find all divs that were fixed and changing them to relative before executing the above line but still the banner does not work. The error is shown in the following picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0sCu8aj8zu2akhtcEdtajJJZEU/edit?usp=sharing

Please Help.

And I am not looking for ad revenue here this is just a practice task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGc5p/4/) I have created. The banner div is at the top of the page.

It stays at the top while scrolling.

The HTML:

```
<div class="page">
</div>
```

The css:

```
.oldBody
{
    width:100%;
    height: 3000px;
    background-color: navy;
    margin-top:250px;
}

#banner 
{
    position:fixed; 
    top:0px; 
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    width:100%; 
    height:250px; 
    border:2px solid; 
    z-index:10000;
}
```

The JS:

```
$("body").wrapAll("<div class='oldBody'></div>");
$("body").prepend("<div id='banner'></div>");
```

Comment: The page should be pushed down

Comment: Currently I can't see the navigation links on the top right corner of google's home page when I run this practice example

Comment: You did not ask for it in the question. I will try to help you

Comment: loffe I have been at it for sometime but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Please maintain z-index of banner div.Z-index should be grater then other div on that page.

```
#banner {
position:fixed; 
display:block; 
top:0px; 
background-color:#FFFFFF; 
width:100%; height:250px; 
border:2px solid;
z-index : 99999 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd just like to present a different way to create the element:

```
var $banner = $('<div/>', { 'id' : 'banner' });
$('body').prepend($banner);
```

this technique for creating elements with jquery comes in handy when you have several different element to create. as a note, you can also create the element like so:

```
var $banner = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'banner');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is first keep your ad on top in relative position when a person scroll page your function check the page-scroll .scrollTop() and then add fixed position on banner ad container just like freeze header, if you need further help in this regard let me know, I will provide you code. thanks I hope this technique will help you

Comment: Actually I have created this as a google chrome extension. When I activate the extension the page contents should be pushed down and the banner inserted on top.